# Broken Windows 10 and product keys

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I just broke the Windows 10 install on my laptop because of a mistake I made while trying to install Linux(Arch linux,more accurately) along with Windows 10.
Here is the question,can I keep the product keys on my hard drive while reinstalling Windows?(Actually,I don't think the product keys can survive this)If not,how can I at least retrieve them?

Comment: As long as you signed in with a Micrsoft account then your product key is stored with Microsoft and you should be able to skip entering the product key in the installer.

Comment: @Mokubai You mean the Windows 10 product key?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.

Comment: @Mokubai I did some research on Microsoft's site,but according to the information I found,reinstall/recover Windows installation does not requires product key.Is it true?

Comment: If UEFI it's already stored

Comment: @MichaelBay How do I check it?

Comment: Check what?  If your device came with Windows 10 then Windows will automatically activate. If that’s not happening it means you installed the wrong version of Windows 10. Retrieving your license keys won’t help you activate Windows 10 it is a complete waste of your time.

Comment: As above. One of the many advantages of UEFI over the 40+ years old BIOS is the ability to store some data including product keys. Any computer sold with Windows 8 or newer is UEFI based. Windows can be reinstalled at any time and provided it's the same version it will activate automatically. So, that's one thing you don't have to worry about. Now the first thing to do is repair or reinstall Windows, then you can try the dual boot again but better with an easier distro like Ubuntu. Arch is likely to be too complex for you. It's not for me and I've been using Linux since Mandrake was the thing

Comment: @MichaelBay what about the preinstalled software,such as MS office?

Comment: There's no preinstalled software if installing with the standard Windows 10 ISO. The manufacturer's recovery should contain the exact same software as provided, the same as booting it for the first time.

Comment: @MichaelBay what i mean is the product keys,not the product itself.does UEFI stored them?

Comment: I guess it's only for the OS, when required.